# HTML: image doesn't display

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRL1w.png)

when I use notepad++ it's fine but when I move to Vscode it won't show up in browser
I'm a newbie in this field, and this is the first time I use Vscode , please help.

```
 <img height="300" width="100"src="mysf.jpg">
```

Comment: Both `index.html` and `mysf.jpg` should be in the same folder. Also, check if image filename is `mysf.jpg` or `mysf.jpeg`. I made the same mistake as a beginner many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than just giving the name of the image, it’s better to give the whole path of where the picture is on your device -

```
 <img height="300" width=“100" src=“/User/…/…”>
```

This will help.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the grammar of the img tag, you can see my example below, it can be displayed normally, this is related to the path of the resource on your website, you should proceed in this direction

```html
<img height="20%" width="20%"src="https://www.happycoding.today/storage/cover_images/%E6%9C%AA%E5%91%BD%E5%90%8D.jpg_1541838726jpg">
```

Because there is too little information on the website, here are two suggestions for you

1. Confirm what is the correct relative path
2. Instead of using relative paths, use absolute paths instead

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) are more concepts and examples of file paths, you can refer to this study